Poweshell to set Azure SQL Auditing
I am trying to use powershell and possibly diagnosticsettings to set the below values in sql server (red ones)

and send the log to Event hub,
here is my ps script:
New-AzDiagnosticSetting -ResourceId "/subscriptions/subid/resourceGroups/rgname/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/servername" -Name "dignnosticsettingname" -EventHubAuthorizationRuleId "/subscriptions/subidofeventhub/resourceGroups/rgofeventhub/providers/Microsoft.EventHub/namespaces/namespaceofeventhub/authorizationrules/sqlserver-sendkey" -EventHubName "sqlserver" -Log @(
    (New-AzDiagnosticSettingLogSettingsObject -CategoryGroup "SQLSecurityAuditEvents" -Enabled $true),
    (New-AzDiagnosticSettingLogSettingsObject -CategoryGroup "SQLInsights" -Enabled $true)
)

Error:
New-AzDiagnosticSetting : CategoryGroup: 'SQLSecurityAuditEvents' is not supported, supported ones are: '' ,......

when I do it manually in the portal it appears as  set server blob auditing policy while when I run my ps command it appears as create or update resource diagnostic settings in the operation type of activity log with some error similar to the above error
What is the correct PS syntax/command?
This MS document has some instructions but I can't figure out the correct syntax or command type
Update:
It seems Diognastic setting gets updated, but not sure how, as nothing is changing in the portal

Also I am not sure whether SQL audit as part of Auditing (databsae and Server) is required as there is an audit category group on the SQL Database.


Please note SQL Server only has Audit, Database has Diagnostic settings and Audit. Do we need to set Audit in both server and database?
UPDATE:
Following the answer provided by Pratik:
In case you can set the audit conf in the portal and not in the Powershell, make sure your subscription is set to the correct subscription as you may receive an error similar to The client ... does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Sql/servers/extendedAuditingSettings/read' over scope .... /extendedAuditingSettings/default or the scope is invalid.
To get the subscription:
Get-AzContext
To set subscription:
Set-AzContext -SubscriptionName SubscriptionName
SQL database Diagnostic settings can be done by he below command:
New-AzDiagnosticSetting -ResourceId "/subscriptions/subid/resourceGroups/rgname/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/servername/databases/dbname" -Name "diagniosticname" -EventHubAuthorizationRuleId "/subscriptions/subid/resourceGroups/rgname/providers/Microsoft.EventHub/namespaces/namespacename/authorizationrules/sharedaccesskeyname" -EventHubName "sqldatabaseserver" -Log @(
    (New-AzDiagnosticSettingLogSettingsObject -CategoryGroup "allLogs" -Enabled $true),
    (New-AzDiagnosticSettingLogSettingsObject -CategoryGroup "audit" -Enabled $true)
) -Metric @(
    (New-AzDiagnosticSettingMetricSettingsObject -Category "AllMetrics" -Enabled $true)
)

Also note by enabling Audit settings by using Set-AzSqlServerAudit, audit settings will be enabled on the database automatically:


Not sure about this at all (suggesting it as an potential option) but should you possibly be using Set-AzSqlDatabaseAudit ? See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/auditing-manage-using-api?view=azuresql and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.sql/set-azsqldatabaseaudit?view=azps-13.0.0

Not sure, however, could you spot an issue here  : Set-AzSqlDatabaseAudit -ResourceGroupName "RGNAME" -ServerName "ServerNAME" -DatabaseName "dbaname" -EventHubName "evntame" -EventHubAuthorizationRuleResourceId "/subscriptions/subidofeventhub/resourceGroups/rgofeventhub/providers/Microsoft.EventHub/namespaces/eventhubnamespace/authorizationrules/evntame-sendkey"
getting this error: "does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases/extendedAuditingSettings/read' over scope
.....",   which is strange because I can set it manauly in the portal

By the way, I'm not sure if you want/need AzSqlDatabaseAudit or AzSqlServerAudit (e.g., for Set/Get/etc) - it may be the Server (and this may also be the reason for permissions). To work out what it should be, you could try setting it in the portal, and then do a relevant Get e.g., Get-AzSqlServerAudit to ensure all the parameters you're setting are correct.

I am sure this is not due permission as I can do any change in the portal, I think I need to do in both (server and database)

To enable Azure SQL Auditing and Auditing of Microsoft support operations in Azure SQL using Powershell you need to use below commands:
To enable Azure SQL Auditing for SQL server:
Set-AzSqlServerAudit -ResourceGroupName "ResourceGroupName" -ServerName "ServerName" -EventHubTargetState Enabled -EventHubName "EventHubName" -EventHubAuthorizationRuleResourceId "/subscriptions/subscriptionid/resourceGroups/resourceGroupsname/providers/Microsoft.EventHub/namespaces/eventhubname/authorizationrules/RootManageSharedAccessKey"

To enable Auditing of Microsoft support operations for SQL server
Set-AzSqlServerMSSupportAudit -ResourceGroupName "ResourceGroupName" -ServerName "ServerName" -EventHubTargetState Enabled -EventHubName "EventHubName" -EventHubAuthorizationRuleResourceId "/subscriptions/subscriptionid/resourceGroups/resourceGroupsname/providers/Microsoft.EventHub/namespaces/eventhubname/authorizationrules/RootManageSharedAccessKey"

Final output:

Make sure the account or service principal being used has the necessary permissions to read the Extended Auditing Settings of an Azure SQL Database. To assign a role follow the below steps:

Go to the SQL Server >> Access control (IAM) >> Add role assignment >> Assign Reader or Contributor role to the user or service principal >> Search for the specific user or service principal, select it, and save.

